# Is this for-loop valid using OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am in the process of learning OpenMP . This is a for loop I am using

```
std::string result;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp parallel for public(local_arg) reduction(+:result)
        for(int i=0 ; i<Myvector.size();i++)
        {
            result = result + someMethod(urn,Myvector[i]);
        }
    }
```

Now `someMethod(urn,Myvector[i])` which will called by multiple threads in the above code will return a string. This string needs to be appended to the return string. My question is do I need to put a lock on the statement in the for loop ? Is there a better approach ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to put a critical section around the mutation of `result` this way. I'll write up an alternative in an answer.

Comment: Thanks looking forward to that. Also I wrote up something els using reduction. Not sure if that will help

Comment: Which compiler? Probably you can use concurrency/parallel library of the compiler.

Comment: I am using openmp2.0  visual studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect (and it's been a while since I've used OpenMP), but the idea is basic divide-and-conquer.

```
std::vector<std::string> results;

int n = 2*omp_get_num_threads();
results.reserve(n); // For reliability, ask OS about # of cores, double that.

// Reserve a small string for each prospective worker
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    std::string str{};
    str.reserve(worker_reserve);
    results.push_back(move(str));
}

// Let each worker grab and mutate the string
// corresponding to its worker ID
//
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < Myvector.size(); ++i)
{
    auto &str = results[omp_get_thread_num()];

    str.append(someMethod(urn, Myvector[i]));
}

// Measure the total size of the result
std::string end_result;
size_t total_len = 0;
for(auto &res : results){
    total_len += res.length();
}

// Reserve and combine
end_result.reserve(total_len + 1);

for(auto &res : results){
    end_result.append(res);
}
```

However, there is still the issue of heap contention.

Also `omp_get_num_threads` isn't guaranteed to return the actual number of threads.

Comment: Also how do I get the maximum no of thread count to work in the loop that might be available to me

Comment: It isn't predictable. OpenMP uses the system thread pool, and the policy is typically "as many as possible". I think I might need to tweak the answer a bit...

Comment: Could you kindly do that. Also why are you doing `results.reserve(threadcount)` ? The threadcount can be less than the contents of the vector.I  believe it should be `results.reserve(Myvector.size())`

Comment: Your code is concatenating strings. The idea is to reserve space for as many result strings as there could be threads running in the work group. Each worker in the group would then concatenate its own string.

Comment: what is the first loop doing ?

Comment: The first loop reserves a small amount of space into a string for each prospective OpenMP worker. This is just an attempt to reduce heap contention for a small workload.